# Mysql query with AND and OR operator not working as expected in Sqlite Database

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a following mysql query that is working perfectly, however when i query the same query on sqlite database it is showing more rows than expected.

```
SELECT word,point,length(word) as len 
FROM table 
WHERE 
(word LIKE '%A%' OR word LIKE '%P%' OR word LIKE '%L%' OR word LIKE '%E%') 
AND 
(length(word)<=5) 
order by point desc
```

Mysql query produces 23 rows while sqlite shows 10693 rows which is not expected. Is there any thing i need to change in sqlite platform?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually *looked* at the returned rows to see what's "wrong" with them? If there's >10k rows returned and you expect 23, most of them should be "wrong". If you find more than 23 that match the criteria, then it's your data that is "wrong", not the query. If you find it returns data that doesn't match the criteria, include the wrongly returned data in the question.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo: Yes, it returned rows that is not correct. According to the query it should return the rows containing only the letters A,P,P,L,E(for eg. APPEL, APPLE, PEPLA etc.), but SQlite shows words composing with letters other than A,P,P,L,E(For eg. JAZZY, JUPON, PLACK etc.). Thanks

Comment: Your understanding of what the query should do is incorrect. It'll return any less-than-six-letter word that contains any of the letters A, P, L, E. If you had `AND` instead of `OR`, and the letters were unique (APPLE has P twice, so they're not), then the "list all the letters" and constrain the length would work like you expect. Here, it will not.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo: Yes you are correct. I just realized it now. What modifications in the query will make it work as expected? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I didn't really come here to answer the question, just to point out that you need to add more details to the question for anyone to be able to reasonably answer it. But let's see... You could count the occurances of each letter in the word, respectively, and check that their sum is equal to the length of the word. There's of course other - perhaps easier/faster - ways to do it if you store the data in a different table layout. Depends on what you're trying to do, exactly, on the grand scale of things, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the query is not working correctly on both mysql and sqlite. I wanted to make it return the rows containing only the letters A,P,P,L,E(for eg. APPEL, APPLE, PEPLA etc.), but the query shows words composing with letters other than A,P,P,L,E(For eg. JAZZY, JUPON, PLACK etc.). I have made the query to include very nearest expected result. Remaining can be filtered out using php or any language as needed.

```
select * from (SELECT word, point, ( ( LENGTH(word) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( word, "A", "") ) ) + ( LENGTH(word) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( word, "P", "") ) ) + ( LENGTH(word) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( word, "L", "") ) ) + ( LENGTH(word) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( word, "E", "") ) ) ) AS COUNT FROM table where length(word)<= length("APPLE") ORDER BY `table`.`word` ASC ) as inner_table WHERE length(word)=COUNT
```